# Could a Hydra take over the world?

Tags: internal-consistency, government, politics, mythical-creatures

Grim Ripper, a 10 story tall monster hydra which looks like a serpent with nine heads, the head in the middle being the biggest head. If one head is cut of, 2 more heads grow in it's place.The middle head can't be cut of. He has super advanced technology, lots of spies, and a home base in North Korea. Some clarifications:
He has to take over at least the Americas and Asia.
He has to secretly manipulate the governments like a puppet master working behind the screens.
He has to take over the world in 60 years. He's immortal, which means he's invulnerable and old age won't kill him. He can't join a secret society or world controlling position because then there would be proof that hydras exist.
If so, how can Grim Ripper rise to power?
Note: I'm not a hydra!!!

Comment: Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]! We're glad you could join us! Please take a moment to [learn more about our culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) and take our [tour]. Please read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). The problems with questions like this are they are not objective and tend to be very broad. Understand that [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107#92110).

Comment: "He's immortal.." - Metaphysically immortal, or just invulnerable?

Comment: I don't understand the question.
Are you asking if the Hydra can with sheer power and strength defeat the armed forces of the world?
Or if it can reliever a surgical strike to intimidate people?
Or does it want to rampage like Godzilla? 
The limitations are power need to be explained. 
Is it pure magic that  prevents the head from destruction or a fictional element like adamantium? 
Because CBRN exist even if the armor is too strong for conventional weapons, I mean we have nukes so not sure. And if it is magical what is the limitations?
Please try to provide and clarify those points

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realistic Megafauna that preys on humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/190739/40609).

Comment: If you're asking about whether an individual can take over that's dependent upon the individual and the specifics of your world. In short you will have had to build your world before we can answer the question. As such it is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Revelations suggests that the hydra will do this by cornering global commerce.**

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2013&version=KJV

> Revelations 13:17:  And that no man might buy or sell, save he that
> had the mark, or the name of the beast, or the number of his name

Revelations 13 in fact lays out the plan pretty well with minor differences as regards # of heads, # of months to accomplish the plan etc.  Hydra healing powers are covered.   I imagine the hydra must have financial software which is required to conduct all commerce.  Also (13:15) people who do not worship the Beast will be killed.  That helps the world domination piece.

Between cornering commerce and getting everyone to worship him (or maybe his friend beast) Revelations is about as well vetted a plan for a many headed monster to take over the earth as you are likely to find.

Comment: It's not everyday that the Bible comes with a pre-assembled answer for a question. +1.

Comment: According to this answer, [EMV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMV) is the Hydra...

Answer (score 3):

How dumb does this Hydra think we are? Posing as a human and asking questions about how to take over the world on a world building site. Puh-lease.

"It's a trick - get an axe."